# Sleep() is a bad design, but appears to be my only option

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, sleep

I'm writing an IO class to upload/download files to a controller over RS-232 serial. Unfortunately, I cannot send a whole file all at once, I have to break it into packets and send it a little bit at a time. Here's the basic approach...

```
ifstream file ("path/to/file.ext", ios::in | ios::binary);

while( !file.eof() )
{
    //... zero buffer, and add packet header (8 bytes)
    size_t nResult = file.read( &buffer[8], 129 );
    Serial.Write( buffer, nResult+8 );
    //... see if controller wrote anything to the serial port and process it's command
    Sleep( 600 );
}
```

I know that using Sleep() is not a good design practice, but if I remove the Sleep() statement or even shorten the amount time the loop sleeps, then the controller throws errors about it's buffer being full, and the transfer fails. **Is there a better way to do this?**

Before you say it, no I cannot send a message to the controller to determine if it's ready for the next packet. It does not have that functionality.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the interval at which I'm having to sleep is somewhat "blind." The protocol specification provided by the manufacturer does not detail any length of time needed between packets. So I had to determine that value by trial and error. I'm afraid that it may not work on every PC and more so that it may not work on every controller.

This development is being done for Windows XP/Vista/7.

**Edit #2:**
Also, the amount of data per packet is actually a trial and error guess as well. The protocol specification allows for packets of 65,535 bytes (including the header). But if you send more than 129 bytes at a time, you start seeing issues where sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. There also seems to be a relationship between the time you have to sleep and the amount of bytes you can send. If I drop the packet size down to 20 bytes per packet, I can drop the sleep time down to 400 milliseconds. I believe the reason for these issues stem from the time it takes to the controller to move data from its buffer to the file.

Comment: Do you always get an answer from the controller?

Comment: If your hardware requirements include sending so many bytes at a time and then waiting so many milliseconds, there isn't an obviously better way to implement it.

Comment: Yeah i would even daresay that using sleep is not that bad of an idea. I suppose you could write a fancy function including <ctime> but given your conditions, Sleep() sounds reasonable.

Comment: Since when is sleep a bad design practice?!

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: I don't think that's related.  That just delegates this exact same functionality to a library thread instead.

Comment: Usually you use select() which suspends your thread until the buffer has space. But without knowing the type `Serial` it imposable to give any real advise about the above code.

Comment: @dwo, No, the controller does not indicate whether transfer was successful or not. If I remove the `Sleep()`, then the controller does one of two things: (1) Halts, (2) Only receives portions of the file (i.e. file is corrupted).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing is called blind-cycle synchronization.  It is not necessarily bad design.  If your device does not have the functionality to indicate that it is ready for more data or not, this is the only way to do it.

It is common for devices to specify a maximum data rate, or minimum amount of time between bytes.

I think the idea of this being bad practice comes from cases where you blindly pick a delay value (performance will suffer if it is larger than it needs to be), if you have better synchronization methods available, or if you are using delays to cover up timing problems (say, in a multithreaded application).

Answer (score 2):

Another reason Sleep might not be the right thing is you may want the functionality to quit early. If you instead did

```
WaitForSingleObject(hTerminatingEvent, 600);
```

You could have another thread signal the event that you want to quit and terminate early. (In this case this function call will continue after 600 ms even if the event isn't signaled.)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I'd use a waitable timer for this instead of `Sleep()`, but if your hardware needs delays, then you're going to need delays.